# Linear Algebra, Invariant Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

State if $M$ is invariant subspace for each of the following linear operators from $L$ to itself:
a)$L=\langle e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4 \rangle,\quad M=\langle e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4,e_1+e_2−e_3−e_4 \rangle$,

$D(e_1) = e_1 +2e_2 −2e_3 −3e_4, D(e_2) = 2e_1 +e_2 −2e_3 −e_4, D(e_3) = 5e_1 +5e_2, D(e_4) = 2e_3 +2e_4$

Anyone know how to do this and would be willing to help me out?